# Microsoft IE open dialog Box and Microsoft Edge Open Dialog Box Different in behaviour

Tags: asp.net, excel, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

We have ASP.Net application - User clicks on a link and system show and an open dialog box with FROM (URL) as a label - User then clicks OPEN. Excel file open in EXCEL as READ-only- Excel File Path shows the URL path and this URL path then use to run VBA code.

In Microsoft Edge
This behavior change and OPEN action save the file in the local system in a GUID folder - Open in EXCEL as READ-WRITE mode and path show the local drive. Further actions will not run as the EXCEL file path is no longer belongs to the URL.

There are 10 Thousand EXCEL online files and many offline files. Hence we can't change application logic. Does anyone face the same issue and have any? solution/suggestion?

Please note that it works fine in IE Compatible mode but we want to run the app in NON-IE Compatible mode.

Comment: Which version of Edge are you using? I try to open excel files in IE and Edge Chromium, but the behaviors are the same. Could you please provide [a minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**? I think it can help us to understand the issue better, then we can see how to help.

Comment: Edge version is  89.0.774.45

Comment: I will get the code tomorrow. As I explained above that when user click on link than a URL will build with fulll File name. Browser show dialog box, user click on open..Both browsers open the file (IE open file but workbook path still show  URL not any local folder-This is what we want)...Chromium download the file in  random local folder after saving file and eventually show local path. In this logic next code can't figure out that from which path this file downloaded and where to get next file.

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? You can come back anytime when you have the code.

Comment: Issue is still exists - Microsoft seems know about it but not found any solution. Sorry got busy to bring sample code.. Let me get this today

Comment: Not placing full code but sample lines :

Comment: string downloadpath = "https://......./folder/filename.xlsm";
system.diagonastics.process.start (download path);

Comment: Original Lines : use this as for testing ---- Public Void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
HttpResponse  response = HttpContext.Current.Response
HttpReqeust request = context.Request;
string session = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
.....
.....
.....
response.ClearContent();
response.ClearHeaders();
response.Buffer = true;
response.ContentType = file.ContentType
response.BinaryWrite (file.FileData);
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","FileName=Somefilename.xlsm");
response.Flush();
}

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. It's not related with the backend code and it's by design in different browsers. I think we can't change the behavior by code so maybe you have to change the logic if you want to use Edge without IE mode. You can try to get the url path when you click the link, and pass it to your VBA code.

Comment: Thanks. We know it;s by design but what will be the solution - It's come from Portal and we do  not have control over it. Is there any 3rd Party Extension will work or code to add in the file  title etc

Comment: I have no idea about such 3rd party extension. Let's wait and see if there're other community members have other ideas.